# Extract body section from the HTTP response in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

Can anyone help me in figuring out how can I extract body from the headers section in the following response using bash scripting.

I have tried awk, sed, grep ... by looking some of the existing solutions here on SO, but with little success.
Let me know if I need to provide any additional info.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Mon, 24 Jul 2017 10:16:19 GMT
Etag: "359670651+gzip+ident"
Expires: Mon, 31 Jul 2017 10:16:19 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
Server: ECS (iad/182A)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 1270

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 1em;
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        div {
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border-radius: 0;
            padding: 1em;
        }
    }
    </style>    
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I didn't explain correctly, what I meant is to extract the body from http response and not body of the html response. In other words, how can extract http's body response in general (the part in the response after \r\n\r\n), this code is just for demo purposes...

Comment: How should your expected output look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About parsing html and extract data using shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994113/about-parsing-html-and-extract-data-using-shell)

Comment: @JFS31 it should start after \r\n\r\n ie. only the body part from <!doctype html>

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '/<body>/,/<\/body>/p' filename
```

Print everything from  to

Answer (score 0):

To output the `body` inner HTML(without the `body` tag):

```
sed -n '/<body/,/<\/body>/{//!p}' file
```